# Double Wildcard SSL Certificates

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, wildcard-subdomain

Is there a registar that offers SSL certificates for:

*.*.domain.com

or

something_fixed.*.domain.com?

--

M.

Comment: Wouldn't `*.example.com` cover `*.*.*.*.*.*...*.example.com`?

Comment: Not a chance.  This was the behaviour of mozilla browsers until relatively recently, but it violated the RFC and they fixed it.

Answer (score 9):

Actually, wildcards only work on the first level of a subdomain in most browsers. So a wildcard certificate for *.example.com wouldn't work on mail.test1.example.com.

Web browsers also don't know what to do with a certificate for somthing.*.example.com either. You best option is to get a SAN certificate that you can include the specific hostnames in no matter what level they are on.

Comment: "wildcards only work on the first level of a subdomain in most browsers". Do you have any references for this? I'm not disputing, just curious.

Comment: Certainly. RFC2818 (http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2818.txt) states:

"If more than one identity of a given type is present in the certificate (e.g., more than one dNSName name, a match in any one of the set is considered acceptable.) Names may contain the wildcard character * which is considered to match any single domain name component or component fragment. E.g., *.a.com matches foo.a.com but not bar.foo.a.com. f*.com matches foo.com but not bar.com."

Comment: +1 Wildcard certs do indeed only work for the first level subdomain.

Answer (score 1):

In case it helps anyone, double wildcard certs don't actually work.

(from firefox)
`www.test.example.com` uses an invalid security certificate.

The certificate is only valid for `*.*.example.com`

(Error code: ssl_error_bad_cert_domain)

Answer (score -1):

As ceejayoz says - a standard wildcard certificate will do exactly what you desire.

I assume you're looking for that style of certificate because you want something cheaper? If so, then no can do, you have to purchase a wildcard.

Answer (score -2):

As wildcard SSL certificate is used to secure unlimited number of sub-domains(first level).

**Example 1:** 
To secure *.domainname.com, you need to buy Wildcard SSL certificate for Doaminname.com,

Here in this case, domainname.com will be your first level domain.

**Example 2:** 
To secure something.*.domainname.com, you need to buy wildcard for *.domainname.com,

Here in this case, *.domainname.com will be your second level domain.

Comment: *Example 2* is simply wrong; see Falcon's comment on the original question.  *Example 1* has nothing to do with the question as asked.