# Can a wildcard SSL certificate secure host names of various depths?

Tags: domain-name-system, ssl, ssl-certificate

I discovered recently that my `*.domain.com` cannot be used on server1.apps.domain.com because it will only "wild" the one level, not two.

The questions are thus twofold:

1. Is there such a thing as a `*.*.domain.com` certificate?
2. Would such a certificate work on both server1.apps.domain.com and www.domain.com? (e.g. two different levels of depth)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do I have to buy a second wildcard certificate for a subdomain?](https://serverfault.com/questions/627219/), [Wildcard SSL certificate and subdomain levels](https://serverfault.com/questions/257404/), [Double Wildcard SSL Certificates](https://serverfault.com/questions/131431/), [Wildcard SSL certificate for second-level subdomain](https://serverfault.com/questions/104160/) and probably more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer is simple:
No there isn't.

According to the RFC only one wildcard is supported:

> Matching is performed using the matching rules specified by
>   [RFC2459].  If more than one identity of a given type is present in
>   the certificate (e.g., more than one dNSName name, a match in any one 
>   of the set is considered acceptable.) Names may contain the wildcard
>   character * which is considered to match any single domain name
>   component or component fragment. E.g., *.a.com matches foo.a.com but
>
>   not bar.foo.a.com. f*.com matches foo.com but not bar.com.

However what you can do is to get a wildcard certificate for *.apps.domain.com which will cover every sub domain of apps.domain.com and another one for *.domain.com to cover the first level subdomains.

Taken from: https://www.instantssl.com/articles/can-you-create-a-wildcard-ssl-certificate-for-two-levels.php:

> The reasons it is not possible to have a "double wildcard" SSL
>   certificate is that the placeholder, the asterisk, can only stand in
>   for one field in the name submitted to the CA. After all, the CA has
>   to verify all information, and too many variables in the certificate
>   would decrease the security and confidence the certificate provides.
>
> Additionally, and this is important for IT managers and website owners
>   as well, the internal security cannot be compromised as easily. Keep
>   in mind that any type of security issue once an SSL certificate is in
>   place is much more likely to occur from an internal security breach
>   where someone with access to the private key and certificate is able
>   to set up a subdomain website that is actually covered by the SSL.

Answer (score 3):

You can have multiple Subject Alternative Names in a single certificate, every with different level wildcard:

*.domain.com

*.app.domain.com

*.xxx.domain.com

etc.

Comment: Yes but it's not a "real" wildcard certificate then, the certificate needs to be reissued whenever you want to add a new subdomain name, e.g. when you have a wildcard for *.example.com with Subject Alternative Name *.apps.example.com you have to reissue if you want to add e.g. *.api.example.com

Comment: Yes. But afaik there is no better way.

Comment: True that. If OP just wants a fixed level of sub-subdomains, this is the right answer.

Comment: Stack Exchange does certs this way, because the RFC says this is how it should work.  The blog post on the transition may be entertaining:  https://nickcraver.com/blog/2017/05/22/https-on-stack-overflow/#certificates